# How to show date field of data table in exported Excel in 'dd MMM yyyy' format

Tags: asp.net, excel, date, gridview

I am able to show date field value in GridView in **dd MMM yyyy (29 Oct 2015)**. After export to Excel, the date field value format is changing to: **dd-MMM-yy ( 29-Oct-15).** My code:

```
Protected Sub btnExportData_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnExportData.ServerClick
    Try
        Dim str As String
        str = HiddenFilterString.Value
        Dim dtExportData As New DataTable
        Dim dtTemp As New DataTable
        Dim dg As New DataGrid
        dtTemp = DirectCast(Session("dtSoHoManageSecretServerFoldersExportData"), DataTable)

        dtExportData = dtTemp.Copy()
        Dim dv As New DataView(dtExportData)
        dg.DataSource = dv
        dg.DataBind()

        Dim sFileName As String = "ServerFolders.xls"
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = True
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & sFileName)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Me.EnableViewState = False
        Dim objSW As New System.IO.StringWriter
        Dim objHTW As New HtmlTextWriter(objSW)
        dg.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = True
        dg.RenderControl(objHTW)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(objSW.ToString())
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End()

        dtExportData = Nothing
        dtTemp = Nothing
        dg = Nothing
        dv = Nothing
        objSW = Nothing
        objHTW = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        ReportInternalError("btnExportData_Click", ex)
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

Is it possible to preserve the same format of GridView in exported Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

-VBA: `Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"`

-Excel Formula: `=TEXT(TODAY(),"dd MMM yyyy")` with VBA:

`Columns("E:E").Copy
 Columns("E:E").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`

-Export the date cells as text, Excel always reads a cell as text if the first character is an `'` apostrophe.